# VB.Net - Toolstrip Button Mousehover Event

Tags: vb.net, toolstrip

Is there a way to change the size of the toolstrip button on mousehover event?

I tried this but didn't work.

```
Private Sub tsDriver_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsDriver.MouseHover
    Dim pt As Point
    pt.X = 60
    pt.Y = 70
    tsDriver.Size = pt

End Sub
```

I'd like to have the effect like, when mouse is hovered on the button, it will grow big and when the mouse leaves it will go back to its original size.

Comment: with mousehover event, I don't think the button will shrink again on leave.

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate a the size, which is a separate object.Try this, it should work;

```
Private Sub tsDriver_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsDriver.MouseHover

    Dim pt As New System.Drawing.Point 
    pt.X = 60
    pt.Y = 70
    tsDriver.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(pt)

End Sub
```

Note that the MouseHover event only triggers when the mouse cursor enters the control location.
So, for the button to shrink to original size, the MouseLeave event should be coded;

```
Private Sub tsDriver_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsDriver.MouseLeave

    Dim pt As New System.Drawing.Point 
    pt.X = 40  ' Original size
    pt.Y = 50
    tsDriver.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(pt)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim pt As New System.Drawing.Point
        pt.X = 60
        pt.Y = 70
        tsDriver.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(pt)
        MsgBox("asdsa")`

Thanks nadeem, I tried it but it didn't work for me. The msgbox will occur tho

Comment: How's that, I just tested on a dummy app and it works fone for me. I hope your `tsDriver` is not in a container or has been docked though

Comment: It's working if in normal button, but it isn't working on my toolstrip button

Comment: it is docked on the left side

Comment: I found out that it is inside a panel. Does that affect anything on my toolstrip?

Answer (score 0):

Should **only** the button resize? or would it be okay for the rest of the buttons resize as well??

If so, you can Manipulate the ImageScalingSize property of the tool tip window

```
       Dim pt2 As Point
       pt2.X = 100
       pt2.Y = 100

       ToolStrip1.ImageScalingSize = pt2
```

This assumes it's okay for the rest of the buttons to grow as well.